# Sproutcore with Python Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sproutcore

I have a computational backend made in Python Scipy and the frontend and admin section will be made in Sproutcore. What do i need to make the sproutcore run the python engine.

I think i need a python framework that sits between sproutcore and scipy. This framework's only job will be to facilitate communication.

Other option is to use sproutcore on the server as well and a way for it to call the python scipy scripts, if that is even possible

Any advice on the correct approach?
Any recommendation on such a simple glue framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any framework you like!  I happen to like something like [SimpleApi](https://github.com/flosch/simpleapi) atop Flask (which you can run with `nginx`, apache2 or any wsgi-compliant server).  This basically puts an TCP/IP listener on top of whatever python code you like.

I am guessing all you want to expose is essentially `run(some_well_controlled_and_obviously_not_from_the_user_code)`.

Some problems you might encounter:

- where to put generated images, such that the front end can get them.  This gets hairy with expiration, file sizes, etc.  `Beaker` might help here?
- job queuing... some computations take a while.  Now what?  Make the user wait?  AJAX-reload?  Shovel that onto `Celery` or `Zero-MQ`?

Let me know how this comes along.  This is definitely needed, and I have thought about starting a similar project myself.